# While working on two laravel projects at the same time, laravel is trying to access the database of the last project that made a request

Tags: php, apache, laravel

This is super weird, never come across it before. But basically I have a laravel app running ajax requests in the background while I work on a different laravel app.  Whenever I try to refresh the app i'm working on, it gives me a db connection error because app2's tables don't exist on app1's database.

I've check the .env, they are configured differently, I've tried composer dump autoload, I've tried clearing cache.  Not sure what's going on here, it may be apache settings I suppose?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more database configuration file that is database.php which is located in config folder.So first u need to check this file and write your credential in your respective database.